# The use of "with" statement in javascript, in some extreme rare cases

Tags: javascript

First of all i know that:

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source
>   of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Con"
>   paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

**BUT**

If we take a simple function like this **(THIS FUNCTION WORKS GREAT)**

```
function loadImage(url,cb){
 with(new Image)
  onload=cb,
  src=url
}
```

we notice there is nothing **CONFUSING** that could break the code inside the function closures. the only 2 variables we use are `onload` & `src`. Until i don't create `variables, objects,arrays or functions` that i name `onload` or `src` nothing bad should happen.

Said that, my question is:

***The javascript garbage collector should add the `new Image` to the collection directly after been executed ?***

And so have less impact to the memory vs a standard function:

```
function loadImage(url,cb){
 var image=new Image;
 image.onload=cb;
 image.src=url;
}
```

In the above case the `var image` remains inside the function until i execute a new one.
btw. also the code would be much shorter.

```
// preload a image
function loadImage(a,b){with(new Image)onload=b,src=a}

// convert a file to base64
function readFile(a,b){with(new FileReader)onload=b,readAsDataURL(a)}
```

**A demo to play with**

http://jsfiddle.net/5wqm3/4/

Comment: I'm curious *why* this implicit property assignment works as so with DOM elements (Chrome/FF at least); it does *not* work as so for normal JS objects. (And I can't recommend it because it is *not* consistent: `x = {}; with (x) { y = 2 }; x.y // => undefined; y // => 2`)

Comment: Also, "Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode" doesn't help the arguments in favor.

Comment: also i was totally affashinated about the fact that it works with dom elements and more.

Comment: i know that it does not work in strict mode ... i'm more concerned about the fact how not using 'var image=new Image()' has impact in the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all i know that: *Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues*

No, the main issue with the `with` statement is that it prevents certain static optimisations as it introduces new variable names *at runtime*. That's also the reason why it was [forbidden in ES 5 strict mode code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799455/1048572).

> Using the with statement should have less impact to the memory vs a standard function

No. **They perform exactly the same.** When the function ends, the `new Image`/`image` is no more in scope of anything. The `image` variable will be gone in the same way as the `with` statement ends with a closing brace.

> The javascript garbage collector should add the `new Image` to the collection directly after been executed?

Actually, I don't think the object is garbage-collected. It's a DOM element with an alive `load` handler waiting for it, I would assume it is still referenced from the event loop queue. However, that doesn't really matter for your question I think.

Comment: so theoretically the code has the same performance , memory impact but it's shorter?

Comment: if not using strict mode the with function is the better one if i want a short code? And reguarding the onload garbage collector i add a this.onload=null in the cb to break the references?

Comment: Shorter? Yes, apparently, though that will hardly matter when it's gzipped. The one without `with` will execute faster though. I'm not exactly sure about the memory consumption during execution, but the lasting impact is the same.

Comment: ...like always.. your answers are clear like the water in some hidden seas in new zeland. +1 what do you think about breaking the reference with this.onload=null. or should i use removeEventListener? naturally that would break the whole time i spend looking into with / reduce the compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: That's the reference *to* the event listener, I don't know why you would want to break that (preventing the listener from being fired?). It makes your function rather a no-op. I talk about the reference from the background HTTP code that is loading the file *to the image object*. I don't know how exactly browsers handle that, maybe they re-create the JS object when necessary. You would only be able to avoid this by not calling `new Image` and setting a `src` on it to trigger loading.

Comment: Removing the `onload` field after the event has been fired (for compatibility with borken browsers) should not be necessary here, as there is no circular reference established.

Comment: right... no circular.An reguarding the filereader that one is not compatible with old browser... so the with function is the better one. and if using in a sequential way then i should store new Image somewhere and change only the src.thank you.but this is async,... so i could overwrite.

Comment: btw you need to correct the part with the reference as there is no circular.

Comment: I never stated there was a circular reference anywhere?

Comment: "Actually, I don't think the object is garbage-collected"

Comment: in a modern browser if there is no circular reference the object should be added to the garbage collection.

Comment: @cocco: Because I think that an Image object that is currently loaded (and has event handlers attached to it) becomes a *root* reachable object, which prevents it from being garbage-collected. There is no circular reference, which will get it properly collected both in old and modern browsers *as soon as there is no other reference to it*.

Comment: this above sentence is not so clear.. your saying it prevents from being garbage collected because of a eventhandler attached but then you say it's collected both in old and new browsers because of no circular reference.... which one now is appliable to my code?

Comment: Both. There is a root reference to it *while it is loading* (preventing it from being garbage collected), and *after the load listener is executed* there probably is no more reference to it which will make it being collected.