# arabic language in xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have this code:
**html code:**

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('users.xml');
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('usr');
document.write(x.length);
</script>
```

**xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users xmlns="http://localhost" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost users.xsd">
<usr><age>25</age><country>الاردن</country></usr>
<usr><age>30</age><country>مصر</country></usr>
</users>
```

And I want to include the html code in another html document like this:
**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html unicode="utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'users.html';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the output of the javascript code is: 0 while it should be 2 and if I replace the arabic text in the xml document with english text the output become 2.
Why is the arabic text breaking the code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you show the relevant HTTP headers and/or give a live URL for testing? Are there any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this is what I get when running var_dump(headers_list()); "array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.24" [1]=> string(23) "Content-type: text/html" }" and no I don't have a live url and there is no error messages in the browser console.

Comment: What happens if you insert the `script` element directly into the html code instead of using PHP for the inclusion? (I’m just trying to reduce the problem to a simpler case.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela same problem.

Comment: My test, with the code as in the question but with direct inclusion of HTML code rather than with PHP: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/users.html8 Works on IE, Chrome, Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure why you want to include the HTML('users.html') which is not described in your question inside a php page if your using ajax. anyway i see some minor problems in your code.

the correct formatting for utf8 in modern browsers is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"><!-- how to set utf8 in modern browsers -->
<title>Users</title>
<script>
function show(){
 document.body.innerHTML=this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('usr').length
}
window.onload=function(){
 with(new XMLHttpRequest)open('get','users.xml'),onload=show,send()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

this example works(using your xml with arabic language) on ie 10,chrome,safari,ios,android,opera e probably also in firefox.

now if you totally need to include the html inside a php page you need to check some php settings maybe.... with a fast search i found this ...

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

but there are many ways to set the encoding to utf8 & include files...

Personally i wouldn't use your approach if you use ajax... if you insist post your `users.html` so that we have more information about what can cause the problem.

the js code returns properly the length of 2 and the ajax is async, how it should be.
more about ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730

the reason i used `with`: [The use of "with" statement in javascript, in some extreme rare cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24045108/2450730)

note:including a whole html page inside another html page is not a correct way to do, you should only include necessary parts (html elements).

if you have any questions about my code just ask.